# flutterfire No app has been configured yet. Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I made a new app and did the steps in Decs but when I run the app, it is run correctly but still has errors on the console.

This error `6.26.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.` show on the console just when i run the app on simulator for the first time then when i run it again it isn't shown on the console.

my console errors:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           21.1s
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
Waiting for iPhone 11 Pro to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57659/LoVj1aW15Pg=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro...
```

I put `FirebaseSDKVersion` on my `podfile` like this

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# Override Firebase SDK Version
FirebaseSDKVersion = '21.1.0'
```

my `pub file`

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_auth: "^0.18.0+1"
```

I used the same `StatefulWidget` examples of Docs in my testing code  ...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Import the firebase_core plugin
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  // Set default `_initialized` and `_error` state to false
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;

  // Define an async function to initialize FlutterFire
  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Show error message if initialization failed
    if (_error) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text('Error 1'),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    // Show a loader until FlutterFire is initialized
    if (!_initialized) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text('loading'),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(' my awesome app'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text or code.  Copy the text into the question itself, and format it in the same way that you did with the other code, so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: You can edit the question to improve it by using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63025

Comment: @Abdullah Zakhoi Same problem here. Have you found the solution already?

Comment: Funny, I also just received this error

Comment: UPDATE: I updated flutter, restarted everything, now it works

Answer (score 0):

I've tried following your instruction, then running the code for the first time:

This is my output in my console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            9.5s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64016/mUYWhxsVDdk=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11...
```

No error has been detected and been able to display the output in my simulator:

[image]

Here is my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at /Users/user/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (8 weeks ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.0.1, Build version 12A7300
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • iPhone 11 (mobile)          • 7D4A169F-C71D-4B28-8673-4504E28E8919 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

I used the latest version of Flutter.